# How to truncate data by week in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT 1 - Cast (a.count AS FLOAT) / Cast (b.count AS FLOAT) AS percentage 

FROM 

(SELECT Count(DISTINCT request_id) FROM quotes) AS a, 

(SELECT Count(*) 
FROM requests 
WHERE  user_id IS NOT NULL AND state NOT IN ( 'rejected', 'unconfirmed' )) AS b
```

Both requests and quotes table have created_at time column.

Where should I put this line

```
date_trunc('week', quotes.created_at + '1 day'::interval) AS "week_num"
```

to get the table of percentagess truncated by weeks?

Comment: Perhaps you should show sample data and desired results.  What you are trying to do is not clear.

Comment: You calculate `week_num` in both selects (and add it to GROUP BY) and then (outer?) join on it.